# Get the time according to timezone of user - PHP

Tags: php, time, timezone

I am developing a Q/A forum on sports. How do i get the timezone of logged in user so as to post his/her queries according to that timezone. Currently I am doing this

```
Javascript 
var current_date = new Date(); var clock=current_date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; gmt= -1 * clock; 
$.post("receive.php",{gmt:gmt});

Receive.php
<?php // set timezone
if(isset($_POST['gmt'])) 
{
    $_SESSION['timezone']=$_POST['gmt']*60*60;        
}
?>
```

But it won't work for those users who have diabled Javascript. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Have the user set a timezone in their options/settings/configuration. Otherwise, use a default value (server, most popular area of visitors).

Comment: agreed with @MECU: if you can't get it from Javascript then the only usable answers are to have the user enter it manually or just pick a default for them (if you show them the time with a timezone code, it'll make sense to them even if it isn't their local timezone). But in all honesty, when did you last see a browser with Javascript disabled? Are you relying on JS for other features? If so, the question is moot anyway. Also, how can you be sure the user's timezone is set correctly?

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to :
1.Retrieve the ip of your user

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

2.Analyse the ip address using a [geolocation ip database](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php).
3.Get the timezone in this location

Comment: Guys, I just tested the same on FB. They are able to post according to my current local time. Are they using a geolocation ip database.

Comment: Try to use a VPN to check, or change the clock of your computer to check.

Comment: Still they are posting the correct time, and not the changed time of my computer clock.

Comment: @RayZ You presumably have an account on Facebook and perhaps told them your location. They may translate that to a local timezone.